# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I encountered an error

> `Mysql2::Error`: Unknown column 'request.user_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `requests`.* FROM `requests` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `requests`.`user_id`

```
 class Request < ApplicationRecord 
    belongs_to :user
 end
```

I don't know what's wrong I have already changed the schema rake db:migrate renamed user_id to req_id why is it still getting the user_id and not the req_id specified in the updated schema.

Schema.rb

```
t.index ["req_id"], name: "index_notifications_on_from_id"
```

Comment: Add your renaming migration code too.

Comment: @cnnr I have I typed rake:db migrate and added changed the user_id to req_id in the schema

Comment: Do you have migration with your rename in your `db/migrate` folder?

Comment: @cnnr yes placed it in the db/migrate folder

Comment: You have *two* typos in your question: `rake:db` and `belong_to`. If your question is inaccurate, please update it; you don't want people to fixate on irrelevant mistakes in the question itself.

Comment: @TomLord sorry I fixed my typos

Comment: `requests.req_id` is the *foreign key* for the *`users`* table??!! I don't understand why you would make that change. `requests.user_id` is the convention, and makes much more sense.

Comment: Maybe what you actually wanted to do was reverse the relation?? So you'd have: `Request has_one :user` and `User belongs_to :request, foreign_key: :req_id`? This means you'd need to define the key on the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo? It should be

```
belongs_to :user
```

with the s

Comment: When i added the s an error of Can't join 'Request' to association named 'user'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: 2) you move from user_id to req_id? Why the hell? :D anyway, in that case you should use `belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :req_id`